# Changing the background-image with jQuery on an ASP .Net MVC 4 page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, css

I am trying to do something really simple, changing the background image of the page using jQuery every five seconds.

Since the project is an ASP .Net MVC 4 project, it has its corresponding _Layout page, @RenderSection, @RenderBody, and all those nice things that the framework provides. So my problem is that I haven't been able to figure out which element I should target and how to change the image.

The pieces of the puzzle are like follows:

On the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<body>
   <!-- some code that displays the navigation menu links -->

   <div id="body>
      @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
      <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
         @RenderBody()
      </section>
   </div>
   <!-- some more code for the footer and some other irrelevant things -->
</body>
```

I have a style sheet file with the following:

```
.main-content
{
   background-image: url("../Images/slide-1-728.jpg");
   opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Finally the jQuery script is like follows:

```
var backgroundHandler = {
    fileIndex: 1,
    backgroundImageFileName: "slide-1-728.jpg",

    updateBackgroundImage: function () {
        return backgroundHandler.backgroundImageFileName.replace(/-[0-9]+-/, "-" + ++backgroundHandler.fileIndex + "-");
    },

    setBackgroundImage: function () {
        document.body.background = $("#url").val() + backgroundHandler.updateBackgroundImage();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(backgroundHandler.setBackgroundImage, 5000);
});
```

The background actually does get updated every five seconds but on the section where the navigation menu is and the background image that is originally set with the style sheet remains the same.

Instead of the document.body.background statement on the script I tried to do the following:

```
setBackgroundImage: function () {
    var imageUrl = $("#url").val() + backgroundHandler.updateBackgroundImage();
    $(".main-content").css("background-image", imageUrl);
}
```

But when I do that nothing seems to happen, the image is not updated and no visible changes appear on the page.

What is the missing piece of the puzzle?

Comment: What happens if you use `$(".main-content").css("background-image", "url(\"" + imageUrl + "\")");` ?

Comment: @nemesv: Wow, it works!!! Could you put it as an answer with an explanation as to why this was needed please?

Answer (score 0):

Tackle this in two steps.

First - take out the dynamic parts of the background image... change your setBackgroundImage function to something like

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url(some absolute url to an image);");
```

Second - add the dynamic piece back in, making sure that the imageUrl variable has a path to a valid image in it.